# How can I create an openlayers layer which includes the borders for the city?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, gis, openlayers

First of all, I am a newbie in the field of GIS and openlayers so please bear with me. I am using an openstreetmap and would like to show the borders of the governorates on the map while adding a background for each governorate (see image below for an implemented example http://afghanistanelectiondata.org/open/maps/tiles/afghanistan-hillshade-english)

1-I wonder how the background and the borders are drawn? and how they exist no matter how much we zoom in and out?

2- From where are the images with the borders are brought, do we draw them or should we bring a map with the borders and put it over the map?

3- Anyone who has an example which wrap all the concepts all together (preferably with Drupal)?

[image: Map with layers and borders]

Comment: repost or move this to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. The background and borders are pre-rendered tileset, generated and served with [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/). You'll need to do some reading up on creating tiles and using them in OpenLayers.
2. You'll bring the map with the borders and put it over the map. But first, you'll need to create transparent tiles that have the governorates borders on them.
3. Here's a simple OpenLayers TileCache [demo](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/tilecache.html).